# Apple MFI Bluetooth using RN-42 from Roving Networks

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, mfi

I was accepted into the MFI program and purchased a lot of RN-42 bluetooth radios from Roving Networks. They are the Apple versions with 5.43 firmware in them.

When I power one up all of my non-apple devices have no trouble seeing and pairing with the radio. I can even communicate with it in Windows. The problem I'm having is that my iPhone 5 doesn't even see it. My MacBook Pro can see it just fine. Although, I haven't tried to pair it on the notebook yet.

Is there something I have to do to program the radio to pair it with an Apple mobile device? Maybe there's some extra documentation just for Apple that I'm missing? Any help would be great at this point.

Comment: As far as I know all MFI related stuff is under NDA

Answer (score 2):

I tested communication between RN-42-APL with 5.36 firmware and worked fine. However communication between iPhone and RN-42 requires additional chip called authentication coprocessor which must be wired to Bluetooth module (I2C serial bus). This chip is required if you want to establish communication between iPhone and bluetooth module.

Firmware 5.43 has fixed bugs related to authentication, but it doesn't have influence on making connection between iPhone and module.

In addition you have to properly set your module. Without that settings, iPhone will not see your module.

You have to send to module the following commands:

S˜,5\r
SN,\r
SC,0024\r
SD,0704\r
ST,253\r
SO,%\r
T,1\r
SM,0\r
SA,0\r

The most important commands are: SC and SD. Other settings for that commands will cause that your iPhone will not see module.

Comment: Do you have any links to relevant code from the iOS side of things? Once I get paired successfully, how do I talk to the device from an iOS app?